# jenssegers/laravel-mongodb group by year and month

Tags: mongodb, laravel, aggregation-framework

I have a collection named `ad_log` with `created_at` column in unix timestamp format. e.g. `created_at: 1469007877`.
How can I group my records by year and month of the year in laravel jenssegers mongodb library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing that your model is `AdLog` 
Try this :

```
AdLog::raw()->agregate([
   [ "$group" => [
       "_id" => [
           "year" => [ "$substr" => [ "$dateStr", 7, 4 ] ],
           "month" => [ "$substr" => [ "$dateStr", 4, 2 ] ]
       ],
       "count" => [ "$sum" => 1 ]
   ]]
]);
```

Comment: @abdu Tahiri: How can I tell which fields i want to return? And how can I get the year as result in 0000 format. Currently with your query, year format in the output is last three digits of the timestamp.